# Выборка из DataTable при помощи LINQ c суммированием

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, datatable

Есть условная таблица **payment** типа *DataTable*, допустим, в ней есть три поля:
**"AccNum"** (номер счета),
**"Payment"** (платеж),
**"Comission"** (комиссия).
Задача: при помощи LINQ выбрать сумму всех платежей и сумму всех комиссий по определенному номеру счета (**AccNum**). Пробую сделать так:

```cs
var query = from payment in payments.AsEnumerable()
                        where payment.Field<string>("AccNum") == accNum                       
                        group payment by payment.Field<string>("AccNum") into grouped
                        select new
                        {
                          AccNum = grouped.Key,                           
                          PaySum = grouped.Sum (s, s => s.Field<decimal>("Payment")),
                          ComSum = grouped.Sum (s, s => s.Field<decimal>("Comission"))
                        };
```

Но IDE начинает ругаться на синтаксис, не могу сообразить что я делаю не так.
В общей сложности должен получиться аналог вот такого SQL запроса:

```sql
SELECT AccNum, SUM(Payment), SUM(Comission)  
from Payments
where AccNum = x 
group by AccNum
```

Comment: В селекте запятую вместо точки с запятой поставьте в первой строки

Comment: @Александр, это здесь опечатался.

Comment: что такое accNum во второй строчке? Она тоже string?

Comment: @Александр, поправил, спасибо.

Comment: я не про это. Во второй строчке вашего кода сравнивается с переменной accNum
__where payment.Field<string>("AccNum") == accNum__

Comment: @Александр, да. Это условный номер аккаунта по которому происходит отбор и группировка. Аналог 'x' в SQL запросе.

Comment: А в группировке вы не перепутали _sum_ с _payment_?

Comment: проблема не решилась?

Comment: @Александр, решилась, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вот так правильно

```cs
var query = from payment in payments.AsEnumerable()
                        where payment.Field<string>("AccNum") == accNum                       
                        group payment by payment.Field<string>("AccNum") into grouped
                        select new
                        {
                          AccNum = grouped.Key,                           
                          PaySum = grouped.Sum (s => s.Field<decimal>("Payment")),
                          ComSum = grouped.Sum (s => s.Field<decimal>("Comission"))
                        };
```